# Stopping an R script without getting "Error during wrapup" message

Tags: r, error-handling

I wrote an R script which writes messages (progress report) to a text file. I modified the `error` option so that when an error occurs, the error message is also written to that file:

```
options(error = function() {
 cat(geterrmessage(),file = normalizePath("logs/messages.txt"),append = TRUE)
 stop()
})
```

It works, but I get this message in the console/terminal window when an error does occur:

```
Error during wrapup:
Execution halted
```

So I'm thinking there's a better way to interrupt the execution of the script... or is there?

Comment: I suspect you have to remove the `stop()` from this.

Comment: What happens then is that if I run the script with Rscript.exe myscript.R, the error is reported but the script just goes on without stopping.

Comment: Try using q() instead of stop(). The error handler gets called using your stop() function, so stopping from within stop... sounds like a recursion. That *might* be what is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found this inside R source code:

```
if (inError) {
    /* fail-safe handler for recursive errors */
    if(inError == 3) {
         /* Can REprintf generate an error? If so we should guard for it */
        REprintf(_("Error during wrapup: "));
        /* this does NOT try to print the call since that could
           cause a cascade of error calls */
        Rvsnprintf(errbuf, sizeof(errbuf), format, ap);
        REprintf("%s\n", errbuf);
    }
```

`stop()` causes the error handler to be executed. If the `stop()` call occurs within the error handler, R displays the `Error during wrapup:` message and prevents you from the infinite recursion that would occur otherwise.

Do not call `stop()` from inside your `options$error`.

Use `q(save="no", status=1, runLast=FALSE)` instead, that should do exactly what the default error handler does for non-interactive use. See `?options` for the meaning of `options$error` and `?stop` for details about error handling.