# Error during wrapup: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to work on a function to assign week# to participants in a longitudinal dataset. Here is the current

```
week_counter <- function(df, colnamer) {
  df$Weeknum <- with(df, paste0('Week', ave(colnamer, colnamer, FUN = seq_along)))
  setDT(df)[, Weeknum := paste0('Week', seq_len(.N)), colnamer]
  view(df)
}
```

This was working before but when it is part of a package I am getting the error " Error during wrapup: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart". Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: *"Error during wrapup"* suggests recursive `stop`s, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27064043/3358272. Are you certain the error in your package is occurring in this function? How are you calling it?

Comment: its basically coming up with that error every time I try to make a function and use it. I am also getting this: Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart

Comment: Why are you using `view(df)` in the function? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: its just to allow me to see the dataset with the new col, but its not necessary, will taking it out help?

Comment: In this case it likely does no harm: since it invisibly returns its argument unchanged, the function still returns the data (which is what is needed).

Comment: The recursive error handling is a problem, and we don't have enough here to know where it is happening. Are you using R-4 and have something in `globalCallingHandlers()`? Otherwise, check every use of `tryCatch` and `try` in your code (and other packages you are actively using). You might want to check your `~/.Rprofile` (if you have one) if you assign something to `options("error")`. Long-story-short, your error handlers are producing errors, and while most tend to just fail noisily (I don't see how it is recursing), I think that's the place to start looking.